# How to calculate the back-propagation of conv3d in tensorflow manually?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, gradient, convolution, backpropagation

In tensorflow, for 2D convolution there is a useful comment on how the back-propagation w.r.t input and weight can be mapped to 2D convolution again. You can find it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0a8177bbe007d2311b2c7b18445b4514cab8d6f3/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_grad_ops.h#L16).

I know the basic fundamental of back-propagation for the convolution. However, I cannot map the back-prop to the forward conv like the 2D convolution. I also don't want to use matrix multiplication for the back-prop.

Now, I'm looking for something similar for 3D convolution. How we can calculate the back-propagation of a 3D convolution w.r.t both input and weights by using another 3D convolution?

I want to simply have a code working like the following:

```py
with tf.GraientTape() as tape:
  y = tf.nn.conv3d(x, w) # forward pass
  L = tf.math.reduce_mean(y, axis = [1, 2, 3, 4]) # calculate loss for each sample in the batch which can be anything.

dl_dy, dl_dx, dl_dw = tape.gradient(L, [y, x, w])

dl_dx_est = tf.nn.conv3d(dl_dy, w) 
dl_dw_est = tf.nn.conv3d(x, dl_dy)
```

In the above code, we have:

```
x.shape = [batch, in_depth, in_height, in_width, in_channels]
w.shape = [filter_depth, filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]
y.shape = [batch, out_depth, out_height, out_width, out_channels]
```

Now the goal is to have `tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(dl_dx_est - dl_dx)) == 0.0` and same thing for `dl_dw_est`. I probably need to pad/rotate/transpose the w and dl_dy and x but I don't know how?

In summary, having something similar to the comments (mentioned link) in tensorflow code would be ideal.